# D3.js - mousedown not working on touch screen

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am using d3.js and jquery. I have svg rect generated via d3.js like that:

```
svg.selectAll("#background_rect") 
     .data(datafile.dat3)
   .enter().append("rect")      
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date2))-(user_set_size/2) })
     .on("mousedown",  start_drag);
```

And function "start_drag", what should show me the clicked rect:

```
function start_drag() {
    alert(this);
    };
```

It works perfectly in web browsers on computer. But it does not work on tablet with touch screen.

For other non svg elements on that page I am using touch punch and it works well on touch screen even for drag and drop.

What I am missing? Why d3.js ignore my touch events?

Comment: Well you're setting up a `mousedown` handler. You probably want a `touchstart` event handler for that. It looks like you'd want to use D3's drag behaviour though.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you, it works. Other issue is, that if I add `touchend`, it is ignored (done is only the `touchstart`)

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile? that helps.